# Car, road, traffic-lights and an optimization problem.

Tags: optimization, expected-value, calculus-of-variations

Suppose you are driving on a road at speed $V$, and then at a distance
$D$ you see a traffic lights showing "red". You are familiar with that
road and know that the light will stay "red" for a time $T$, but as you
just came around the corner you don't know how long it is already
showing "red".

What is the best strategy to approach the traffic light, when you want
your speed to be as high as possible$^1$ at the moment when the lights are
switching to "green"? Constraints:

1. You are not allowed to pass the lights as long as they show "red".
2. As long as the lights are "red", you must not speed up, i.e.
   $|v(t_2)|\leqslant |v(t_1)|$ if $t_2 > t_1$.
3. You are approaching the traffic lights, i.e. $V>0$, where positive
   speed is towards the lights (in the direction of the road).
4. There is an upper limit for the deceleration of
   $g=9.8\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$, and you are driving at a reasonable[tm]
   speed: It is possible that you can come to a halt before crossing the
   lights, even if the lights are "red" for the maximal time $T$.

The last point constrains the initial speed to $V\leqslant gT$, and thus
the distance must satisfy $D\geqslant\frac12gT^2$ so that

$$D\geqslant\frac12V\cdot T$$

If the distance is big enough, i.e. $D\geqslant V\cdot T$ then the
solution is simply to keep on driving with $V$ because at the moment you
will reach the lights they will have changed to "green".

So let's also assume $D < V\cdot T$ in the remainder.

One strategy is to keep on driving with $V$ and if the lights don't switch
doing a full brake and come to a halt.

But there might be better strategies like braking gradually, which gains
you some extra time in which the lights might turn "green". The speed
$v(T)$ is then not as high as $V$ but that's definitely better than coming to a
halt.

I have no idea how to even formalize this...

Even if we knew  the best strategies for all remaining times $T^{*}$, how
would you average / combine these $v_{T^{*}}(t)$ to get the best solution w.r.t
expected speed at the time the lights are switching "green"?

Presumably a calculus of variations problem?

In addition to the constraints from above, the following clarifications /
simplifications shall apply:

- The road is flat, i.e. no hills or (change in) potential energy.
- You must stay on the road, i.e. the car moves on a prescribed
  trajectory. The road is just a 1-dimensional smooth line$^2$ with the
  lights at distance $D$ ahead.
- The times when you come around the corner and see that the lights are
  "red" are evenly distributed during the "red"-phase, i.e. the average
  time until they switch "green" is $T/2$.
- There is no friction or drag etc.: Change in speed is only due to
  using the brake.
- There are no other cars etc. that would impede you.
- Speed of light is infinitely high.

---

$^1$This is the most energy-efficient way of driving provided braking
just dissipates kinetic energy.

$^2$Without loss of generality we can assume the road is straight,
because change in direction won't dissipate energy as the component of such
acceleration is perpendicular to the direction of motion.

---

### Hint:

The best $v(t)$ is constrained by:

- "Red" lights must not be crossed:

$$0 \leqslant \int_0^T v(t) dt \leqslant D $$

- No speed-up while "red":

$$-g \leqslant v'(t) \leqslant 0 $$

- Must not move backwards and no speed-up:

$$ 0 \leqslant v(t) \leqslant v(0) = V $$

If the switching time is known to be exactly $T^*$, then the optimal
speed at time $T^*$ is given by

$$ v_{T^*} = V - gT^* + \sqrt{g(2D + g{T^*}^2 - 2VT^*)} $$

which follows from a simple geometric consideration. No Idea how to use
that or if it's of any use at all...

Comment: Finally someone asking the right questions

Comment: Are you interested in the maximum average speed or minimum expected energy loss? I assume these objectives have different solutions.

Comment: @Its_me Either case is interesting, in particularly which technology can be used to find solutions when there are nasty inequality / non-holonomic constraints.

Comment: Strangely, I have thought about an almost identical problem while driving on and off over the years, and I even wrote down a calculus of variations problem to try to solve it.  My approach was to try to minimize the sum of (1) the time that I passed the light and (2) the energy dissipated by braking (i.e., how much gas/petrol is wasted) times a conversion constant that will make the units equal.  This conversion constant was to be chosen on the basis of "How much of a hurry am I in?" and "How much do I care about the environment today?"

Comment: I did not make any progress because I kept running into solutions that either required me to drive infinitely fast or infinitesimally slow.  Placing "speed limit" type constraints makes using calculus of variations a lot harder.  Also, another problem is that some of the terms in the functional were perfect derivatives, so calculus of variations ignored them completely.  I don't recall the details now but will look at it again if I have time.  In any case, I would love for someone to find a solution.

Comment: One other comment: I don't think that $ \int_0^T v(t) dt \le D $ is the right model for "Red lights must not be crossed." At the end of this interval, it is almost certain that the light has changed and it would therefore be okay to cross the light. I think that I had tried to model the problem as follows. At any given moment, $t$, there is some probability distribution that the light will change at time $\tau>t$, given that it has already not changed by time $t$. You want to maximize the expected value of some function over this probability distribution to determine the right speed at $t$.

Comment: @sasquires The problem with optimizing the energy is that one gets  energy *gain* if moving backwards is not forbidden somehow: Just accelerate backwards until the lights switch to "green", and then accelerate forward.

Comment: I think this question requires a numerical solution not analytical. I assume numerical is not that difficult.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Yeah, I was trying to solve it without adding a constraint that you can't go backwards and then hoping that if we check the solution, we wouldn't find something like this in the solution.  This is related to another problem that I encountered, which is that you need to put boundary conditions on both $x$ (reaching the light at some point) and $t$ (the problem becomes kind of meaningless if you wait for several light cycles to pass).  This complicates things as well.

Comment: In my experience examining the volume of cross-traffic gives you a clue as to how long the light has been green for them, which should inform your decision.

Comment: I know it's just a math problem but I do want to remind people that timing your drive to go through a light just as it turns green is a dangerous practice.  If somebody in the cross traffic is coming fast to make a stale yellow and runs an early red, you will get creamed.

Answer (score 6):

Since the time at which the light turns green is uniformly distributed over $[0,T]$, your expected velocity at the moment the light turns green is:
$$\int_{0}^{T}\frac{v(t)}{T} dt = \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T}v(t) dt$$
This is simply the distance that would be traveled by time $T$ divided by $T$. Any path $\hat{v}$ that traverses the whole distance D, i.e. 
$$\int_{0}^{T}\hat{v}(t) dt = D$$
will have an average velocity of $D/T$ and be optimal. It does not matter how you decelerate (or even accelerate, go backwards, etc.) so long as you would traverse the whole distance D by time $T$.

---

How to compute fuel efficiency requires we define what fuel efficiency is. Minimizing how much you brake and accelerate:
$$\int_{0}^{T} |v'(t)|dt$$
is equivalent to what maximizing your expected velocity at the moment the light turns green, as was previously answered.

Alternatively, maybe fuel efficiency is equivalent to minimizing the dissipation of kinetic energy? (There is then no reason to ever accelerate as it only makes you go further without increasing the objective function.) If the car does not accelerate, then the problem is equivalent to maximizing the kinetic energy that remains:
$$\int_{0}^{T}\frac{v(t)^{2}}{T} dt$$
Intuitively, because kinetic energy is convex in velocity, this expectation will be maximized by staying at the initial velocity of $V$ for as long as possible, denote this path by $\tilde{v}$. Further, let $F_{v}(\hat{V})$ denote the cumulative density function of velocity, i.e. the probability that velocity is less than $\hat{V}$ when the light turns green. Note that since $v$ and $\tilde{v}$ are non-increasing (supposing no acceleration), $$F_{v}(x) = \Pr[v(t_\textrm{green}) \leq x] = \int_{v^{-1}(x)}^{T} \frac{1}{T} dt = \frac{T-v^{-1}(x)}{T}$$

Claim 1: For any $v(t)$, there exists a $t^{*}$ (not necessarily unique) such that for all $t < t^{*}$ we have $\tilde{v}(t) \geq v(t)$, and for all $t > t^{*}$ we have $\tilde{v}(t) \leq v(t)$.

Proof: Let $\tilde{t}$ be the time at which $\tilde{v}$ starts decelerating, then:
$$t^{*} = \inf \{t\geq\hat{t}| \tilde{v}(t^{*}) \leq v(t^{*}) \}$$
By construction, for all $t < t^{*}$ we have $\tilde{v}(t) \geq v(t)$. Further, since $\tilde{v}$ decelerates as quickly as possible to zero after $\hat{t}$, and at $t^{*} > \hat{t}$ we have $\tilde{v}(t^{*}) \leq v(t^{*})$, it must be that for all $t > t^{*}$ we have $\tilde{v}(t) \leq v(t)$.

Corollary 1: For any $v(t)$, take the $t^{*}$ satisfying the previous claim and let velocity $x^{*} = \tilde{v}(t^{*})$, then for all $x < x^{*}$ we have $F_{\tilde{v}}(x) \geq F_{v}(x)$, and for all $x > x^{*}$ we have $F_{\tilde{v}}(x) \leq F_{v}(x)$.

Claim 2: Any $v(t)$ which doesn't go distance $D$ by time $T$ is not optimal since $\hat{v}(t) = v(t-\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon>0$ is chosen so that $\hat{v}$ goes distance $D$ in time $T$ results in higher expected kinetic energy by delaying any deceleration.

Claim 3: Take any $v(t)$ which goes distance $D$ by time $T$, then $F_{\tilde{v}}$ is a mean preserving spread of $F_{v}$.

Proof: Since both $v(t)$ and $\tilde{v}(t)$ go distance $D$ by time $T$, they have the same mean velocity, which implies that:
$$\mathbb{E}[\tilde{v}(t)] = \int_{0}^{V} 1 - F_{\tilde{v}}(x)dx = \int_{0}^{V} 1 - F_{v}(x)dx = \mathbb{E}[v(t)] = D/T$$
$$\Longrightarrow \int_{0}^{V} F_{\tilde{v}}(x) - F_{v}(x)dx = 0$$
Define:
$$A(\hat{x}) = \int_{0}^{\hat{x}} F_{\tilde{v}}(x) - F_{v}(x)dx$$
Then $A(0) = 0$ and $A(V) = 0$. By Corollary 1, $A$ is increasing for $\hat{x}<x^{*}$ and decreasing from $\hat{x}>x^{*}$. Thus, $A(\hat{x})\geq 0$ for all $x$, and strictly for some $x$ if $F_{\tilde{v}}$ and $F_{v}$ are different.

By Claims 2 and 3, $\tilde{v}(t)$ (strictly) maximizes the expectation of any (strictly) convex function of velocity.

---

In addition to $\tilde{v}$ being a solution to either of the previous optimization problems, notice that it also minimizes the expected distance between the car and the light when it turns green.

I don't believe frictions would really affect the analysis as they are just mandatory braking? We would have to define friction and fuel efficiency to actually show that though.

Other considerations could be considered, e.g. comfort and not damaging the brakes. The point is you can decelerate/accelerate however you like without affecting your expected velocity for when the light turns green as long as you go distance $D$ by time $T$. Or, if you want to maximize kinetic energy, you should wait as long as possible to slow down.

Comment: an interesting (which is another problem it s true) question would be how to optimise fuel, in that case scenario, the decelaration matters!

Comment: That would be interesting, how do you think fuel should be modeled? Like, what would the objective function be mathematically?

Comment: I remember that one can model fuel consumption. An easy model is to simply incorporate it as a "friction": $$ C_{\text{fuel consumption}} = f V_{\text{speed}} $$ 

However, I do think there is a better way to do it. According to wikipedia:

"Generally, fuel efficiency is maximized when acceleration and braking are minimized. So a fuel-efficient strategy is to anticipate what is happening ahead, and drive in such a way so as to minimize acceleration"

So possibly, a simple way seems to be minimizing the acceleration: $$ \text{argmin}_V \int_0^T V^2(t) dt $$

what do you think?

Comment: Acceleration and braking (absolute changes to velocity) are minimized here by the original question of maximizing the expected velocity when the light turns green (while making sure to never accelerate). Since the amount of braking will be equal to the total reduction in velocity.

Comment: Perhaps fuel is related to the change in kinetic energy, which I take is your last expression with velocity squared? (For some reason that doesn't feel right to me? But regardless...) This convexity in speed will mean you want to be at the extremes. As I argued before, the average speed won't be affected, so the answer would be to not slow down until you have to.

Comment: I don't believe friction would affect anything--it's basically just a mandatory level of braking which is perhaps preferable to a car's braking mechanism.  Maybe it is more comfortable to have a constant deceleration or whatever. The main point is you can take whatever other considerations into account without worrying about the average expected speed.

Comment: In response to some of the comments above, I just want to note that I had suggested a measure of fuel inefficiency in a comment above yesterday (essentially the amount of energy lost to braking).

Comment: @SherwinLott Besides not addressing the "fuel efficiency" concern in the question, there are two much more fundamental problems here.  1. You do not have to reach the light at exactly time $T$.  Heuristically, we might expect that your average path should reach it at $T/2$, since that is the average time for the light to turn green.  But, for example, if you happen to see the light change earlier than that, you are free to go as fast as you can (i.e., the speed limit) to reach the green light sooner.

Comment: 2. You cannot brake instantaneously, and you do not know when the light will turn.  You need to think about the probability distribution of when the light will change color to figure out the "optimal" behavior, but there is a hard constraint that you have to be able to stop in time not to run the light.  However, this part could probably be disregarded in the initial solution.

Comment: @sasquires Sorry if my answer wasn't clear, I am saying that any path which would reach the light at time $T$ will maximize the expected velocity. I understand the light can turn green at any point in the interval $[0,T]$, and so the average velocity is:
$$\int_{0}^{T} v(t)/T dt$$
Which is simply the distance traveled if the light turns green at time $T$.  This is maximized by any feasible path that travels distance $D$ by time $T$. Yes, I understand the car cannot break instantaneously, I'm talking about any feasible path.

Comment: The question asked for the path that maximizes the average expected velocity when the light turns green. (I don't believe the question lets you accelerate after seeing the light turn?) I am happy to discuss what maximizes fuel efficiency as I did in my earlier comments, but I need help characterizing fuel efficiency?  For instance, are we trying to minimize the decrease in velocity or in kinetic energy? The former is equivalent to the maximizing the expected velocity which I answered. The change in kinetic energy is minimized by only braking when the constraint binds (happy to formalize).

Comment: @Sherwin Lott: Mean velocity over time was not asked for. What counts is only the velocity at the moment when the lights are switching to "green". The expectation is take w.r.t. to many attempts, since the time to the switch is a random variable.

Comment: @Its_me: Understood, but since the light turns green uniformly over the interval $[0, T]$, is it not equivalent to the average velocity over that time period?  (Where, $v(t)$ is the velocity at time $t$ supposing that the light has not turned green yet.) Perhaps I should edit the answer to make this intuition more clear? Really emphasize it as it is the crux of the argument. (I'm supposing time $0$ is when you enter the street.)

Comment: Yes, the solution is the largest mean velocity averaged over [0,T], but it doesn't look like you think it does, i.e. "don't decelerate unless you have to" is incorrect. Image you go with infinite speed and can brake with infinite speed. Then you are at the light immediately at time 0, you have to brake and have zero velocity. This velocity is averaged across [0,T] which is zero. If you brake at time zero to zero velocity, again, the velocity is averaged across [0,T] which is zero. The optimum is between this policies.

Comment: @Its_me: Instead of infinity, let's pick a large number, say $10^9$m/s.  You get to the light nearly instantaneously: in $D/10^9$ seconds, and then stop instantaneously.  The light turns green during that time period with probability $(D/10^9)/T$. Hence, the expected speed when the light turns green is 10^9 multiplied by the probability, which gives $D/T$! Hence, your example does not contradict my answer (so long as we don't have infinite speeds were we have to worry about multiplying infinity by zero).

Comment: I have now edited the answer for clarity, but I haven't changed the conclusions. Let me know if it's still unclear or if you still think there are counterexamples.  Thanks.

Comment: I see, for velocity maximization you are right for sure. Your argument for maximizing kinetic energy could be expanded a little bit. I checked a few extrem cases and it seems to be true, but it's not obvious in general to me.

Comment: Agreed, the intuition for maximizing kinetic energy needs to be formalized.

Comment: I don't qoite get it... Your optimality condition can't be satisfied in general because if you achieve it for a time t, then you will cross the red lights if T is larger.

Comment: I'm using $T$ as a fixed constant: the maximum possible length of time the light could stay red. My optimality condition only requires that you would get to the light by time $T$ if ends up taking that long to turn green.

Comment: @emacs drives me nuts: Maybe it helps if I formulate it in different (but not better) words: You are interested in a policy what velocity to take, which can be formalized as a function of time $v(t)$ or a function of the distance travelled $v(x)$. Choosing $v(t)$ results in a simple solution. ...

Comment: ... What $v(t)$ are possible? The $v(t)$ have to fulfill all your constraint above, but most importantly at no time point before the traffic light changes $t \le T$ it should be crosssed, i.e. $x(t)=\int_0^t v(t) dt\le D$ for all $t \le T$. That's simply the area under the curve $v(t)$ until time $t$ including $T$. This constraints your possible solutions.  ...

Comment: ... Which one is the optimal? The expected velocity averaged over traffic light switches is $E[v(t)]=\int_0^T v(t) p(t) dt$. For uniform probability of light switches $p(t)$ the expectation value is proportional to the area under the curve $v(t)$. Thus, all those $v(t)$ with the largest area under $v(t)$, i.e. $D$, will be optimal.

Comment: The main problem that I have with this answer is still that it blindly assumes that the OP's footnote (that having "speed be as high as possible" when the light turns green is "the most energy-efficient way of driving") is literally correct in all circumstances, rather than understanding the meaning of what he/she is saying.  If you brake to a halt, accelerate to a high speed, repeat the process a few times, and then reach the light, then you are *not driving in an energy-efficient way*.  A correct answer would need to take this into account.

Comment: OP's main question was: "What is the best strategy to approach the traffic light, when you want your speed to be as high as possible at the moment when the lights are switching to 'green'?" Which is what I answered.  I agree the question of energy efficiency is interesting. If we want to minimize absolute acceleration deceleration
$$\int_{0}^{T} |v'(t)|dt$$
then that is equivalent to the previous question with the caveat that you are not allowed to accelerate. If instead fuel efficiency is absolute changes in kinetic energy, then I've intuition for that. How would you define fuel efficiency?

Comment: @SherwinLott Your first couple of sentences just prove my point.  You are answering a misconception within the question by taking every word literally, rather than answering what the OP is actually asking for.

I think that the obvious way to incorporate fuel efficiency is to minimize the kinetic energy dissipated by breaking.  That is, you also want to maximize the integral of the function

$f(t) = \left{ \begin{matrix} \ddot{x}(t) \dot{x}(t) & \ddot{x}(t) < 0 \\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{matrix} \right.$

Comment: I was unable to get the previous equation to display correctly within the 5 minute time window.  But basically, the idea is that you are integrating $\ddot{x}(t) \dot{x}(t)$, but only when $\ddot{x}(t)$ is negative, which represents "braking."  When you accelerate, you are not really losing energy, but when you brake, then you are losing at least some of that energy irreversibly.  (The amount depends, of course, on how your car's braking system works.)

Comment: @sasquires: We are just going to have to disagree about what OP's primary question was, which is fine. If we want to minimize kinetic energy dissipated (supposing no accelerating as that is clearly never optimal since it only makes the constraint bind further) then that's equivalent to maximizing kinetic energy when the light turns green:
$$\int_{0}^{T} \frac{v(t)^{2}}{T} dt$$
Can we agree on this objective function to maximize? I'll update my solution momentarily, I have a proof of my earlier intuition that uses second-order stochastic dominance, convexity, and Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Okay, I could flesh it out a bit more, but the argument is there.

Comment: @sasquires: I excplicitly asked emacs_drives_me_nuts if he is interested in maximum average speed or minimum expected energy loss and pointed out that the solutions might be different. The answer was "Either case is interesting", so the answer about max. velocity is sufficient to get the bounty, although anwers to both questions are of course geat.

Comment: I've finished editing my answer about kinetic energy. I could flesh out more why $\hat{v}$ and $v$ cross only once and explicitly verify that the crossing point $x$ satisfies the claim. But I believe it's obvious and a bit laborious? The mean non-decreasing spread immediately follows from definitions.  Specifically, the claim is indeed the definition of a mean preserving spread if $v(t)$ had the same mean as $\tilde{v}(t)$. Note that the proof extends to any convex function not just kinetic energy.

Comment: @SherwinLott Ok, I am willing to follow this new section.  I got up to the point where you claim $F_v(x)=T−v^{−1}(x)$.  I do not think this is correct.  $\Pr[v(t_\textrm{green}) < x] = \frac{1}{T} \int_0^{t(x)} dt = \frac{t(x)}{T}$, where $t(x)$ is what you are calling $v^{-1}(x)$, i.e., the time when the velocity passes from greater than $x$ to less than $x$.

Comment: It does need to be divided it by T since it's a cdf and not a measure, thanks!  Merging the way we are writing it:
$$ \Pr[v(t_\textrm{green}) < x] = \frac{1}{T} \int_{v^{-1}(x)}^{T} dt = \frac{T-v^{-1}(x)}{T}$$
With those bounds because I'm supposing $v(t)$ is non-increasing (no acceleration).

Comment: The claim that $F_v$ and $F_\bar{v}$ can only cross once because $v$ and $\bar{v}$ only cross once is questionable, although I am about to propose an interpretation that I think makes it correct. $\bar{v}$ is the piecewise function equal to $V$ up to time $t_0=D/V$ and 0 afterwards. This means that $F_\bar{v}$ is a piecewise function, $t_0/T$ from $0$ to $V$ and then $1$ afterwards. Neither path exceeds speed $V$, so both have to reach $1$ at $V$. They can either cross or not cross before that. I think you're saying that if they do cross, that is $x$, and if not, then $x=V$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I got the bounds wrong, so now the merged answer is correct.

Comment: The last paragraph needs to be clearer. I understand the intuitive argument here (that $v(t)^2$ is convex in $v$ and therefore should be maximized by the same distribution that maximizes $v$). But I don't get the details of the technical argument. According to Wikipedia, to show two cumulative distributions are [mean-preserving spreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-preserving_spread), you have to show (1) that the means of the distributions are the same, and...

Comment: ...(2) that the *area under* one cdf is dominated by the other everywhere.  The existence of a point of intersection could be used as part of the argument for (2), but it is not good enough by itself.

Comment: @sasquires: I agree the last paragraph was lazy. I've now spent an hour typing up a thorough version with a definition of single crossing via $t^{*}$.  Also, note that the proof is written to allow various different rules for braking. Let me know if this is satisfactory, haha... fleshing out the proof is pretty laborious :P.  I'm more of a intuition and picture person.

Comment: Ok, now I am on your side.  Thanks for having the patience to work through all of my objections!  I think this answer will be much more useful to future readers now.

Comment: So, my interpretation in terms of practical advice for driving (incorporating real-world conditions) is the following.  1. There is no benefit to slowing down during the early part of the path.  2. There is no benefit to spurious acceleration.  The only type of acceleration that is worthwhile is maintain the minimum speed to reach $D$ by time $T$.  (Friction may otherwise slow you down enough that you would not reach $D$ in time.)  3. Wait as long as you *safely* can before braking if the light is still red when you are approaching it.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for prodding me along the way to do more than an outline as well as checking my work. I agree with your practical takeaways.